# Compiling VLC android ubuntu

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-ndk, java-native-interface, libvlc

I am having trouble in compiling VLC on Ubuntu. I followed this tutorial 
https://wiki.videolan.org/AndroidCompile/
Everything was going smooth when This issue came up when I tried to run the app from the android studio

> Error:Execution failed for task ':libvlc:buildDebugARMv5'.
>   Process 'command './compile-libvlc.sh'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Along with a message that

> You need the NDKv10 or later

My NDK version is android-ndk-r10e which the latest one. 
My NDK and SDK paths are set in the environment as I have checked them using echo.

If I try to compile from terminal

```
areeb@areeb:~/android$ sh compile.sh -a armeabi-v7a
VLC source found
Configuring
You need the NDKv10 or later
areeb@areeb:~/android$
```

Hope anyone have faced this and have surpassed this as well.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I have managed to solve the problem. The issue is that if we are following the VLC android compile tutorial when they ask to set the ANDROID_NDK the line is written something like

> export ANDROID_NDK=/path/to/android-ndk

Which means you have to export like

> export ANDROID_NDK=$HOME/path/to/android-ndk

If you do this way everything will go fine.

Answer (score 1):

I run into this problem too. In my case nothing helped me (I checked my SDK/NDK pathes and even checked that my NDK/SDK aren't corrupted by checking MD5), so I decided to modify compile.sh this way:

```
# try to detect NDK version
#EL=$(grep -o '^r[0-9]*.*' $ANDROID_NDK/RELEASE.TXT 2>/dev/null|cut -b2-)
#case "$REL" in
#    10*)
    if [ "${HAVE_64}" = 1 ];then
        ANDROID_API=android-21
        GCCVER=4.9
    else
        ANDROID_API=android-9
        GCCVER=4.8
    fi
#    ;;
#    *)
#        echo "You need the NDKv10 or later"
#        exit 1
#    ;;
#esac
```

As you can see, I just commented that check for a NDK version (on line ~280). I know that this is not the good way at all, but at least I was able to run the build.

Comment: I am doing the same myself but this leads to unmanageable dependencies for instance now I a stuck on "make: *** [.fribidi] Error 77
make: *** [.a52] Error 77" and the error in the log file is "error: cannot find -lgnustl_static"

Comment: @Areebgillani which Linux version are you using for VLC compilation? Did you run apt-get update before you start? Did you install all required packages from "Requirments" section from guide?

Answer (score 1):

If you are already having latest version but it is showing the message like

> You need the NDKv11 or later

You can go to file compile-libvlc.sh.Change from

> REL=$(grep -o '^Pkg.Revision.*[0-9]*.*' $ANDROID_NDK/source.properties |cut -d " " -f 3 | cut -d "." -f 1)
>   case "$REL" in
>       11*)

to

> REL=$(grep -o '^Pkg.Revision.*[0-9]*.*' $ANDROID_NDK/source.properties
>   |cut -d " " -f 3 | cut -d "." -f 1) case "$REL" in
>       12*)
>
> The only change is 11* to 12*

That actually solved my problem.If you fear that you will get any issues with new version,download whatever the version it is asked for.Here it is

> v11